# A question about sum of n random variables

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be random variables. We know that $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are $\sigma(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ - measurable. But how about $X_1 + \cdots + X_n$? Is it $\sigma(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ - measurable? Why?

($\sigma(X_1, \ldots, X_n) =$ $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_1, \ldots, X_n$)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every measurable function $u$, $Y=u(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is $\sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$-measurable since, for every Borel subset $B$, $[Y\in B]=[(X_1,\ldots,X_n)\in u^{-1}(B)]$ and $u^{-1}(B)$ is a Borel subset of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: It is true that if $B$ is a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $B = B_1 \times... \times B_n$, where $B_1, ..., B_n$ are Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Of course not. Example: $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x\lt y\}$ is open hence Borel, but not a product. Let me suggest to get a book or any kind of introductory lectures on measure theory.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $X_1 + \ldots + X_n < t$ iff there exist rational numbers $r_1, \ldots, r_n$ such that $r_1 + \ldots+ r_n < t$ and all $X_i \le r_i$.